# Create a class as data structure?

Tags: vb.net, class, data-structures

I am trying to create a data structure `CityPosition`, in which to have 3 variables: `CityName`, `PositionX`, `PositionY`.

I tried creating a class:

```
Public Class CityPosition
   Public Shared CityName As String
   Public Shared LocX As Double
   Public Shared LocY As Double

   Public Sub New(ByVal name, ByVal x, ByVal y)
       CityName = name
       LocX = x
       LocY = y
   End Sub
End Class
```

As I have to collect lots (unknown number) of instances of that class, I created an ArrayList element:

```
Dim CityPositions As New ArrayList
```

Finally, I am trying to add an instance of the class to the ArrayList by this:

```
CityPositions.Add(New CityPosition(Positions(0), LocX, LocY))
```

1. Please let me know if I am doing it right, because I am a VB.NET newbie.
2. How to access the instance properties? I tried `CityPositions(0).CityName` but it seems not to work

Comment: a) Do not use `ArrayList`, but `List(Of CityPosition)`. b) If you have a lot, then use a `Struct` instead of `Class`, same syntax.

Comment: @ja72 - Why use a struct?  A class is better suited for this purpose.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, there is penalty in instantiating and keeping classes in memory. The OP mentions *lots* so I suggest using array of structs which keeps data local and fast. Best would be a struct of arrays though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove "Shared" from your public fields as shown below.

```
Public Class CityPosition
   Public CityName As String
   Public LocX As Double
   Public LocY As Double

   Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double)
       CityName = name
       LocX = x
       LocY = y
   End Sub
End Class
```

Also, it is preferable to use Properties instead of Public fields within a class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx